When to use t-distribution?
Let the dataset $6, 12, 12, 9, 7, 16, 10$ be given. Each data point is considered to be an outcome of a random variable $X_i$, where the $X_i$'s are assumed to be independent and Poisson distributed with mean $\mu$. That is, each $X_i \in \text{Po}(\mu)$. Since the $X_i$'s are Poisson distributed, we estimate $E(X_i) = \mu$ with $\bar{x}$ and $D(X_i) = \sqrt{\mu}$ with $\sqrt{\bar{x}}$. Specify the lower bound for the two-sided confidence interval $I_\mu$ for $\mu$ with an approximate confidence level of 95%.
I don't actually need help solving the problem rather I wanna use this an example. So it was my understanding that if we approximate the standard deviation then we have to use t-distribution but in the solution they used "z-distribution" or lambda as it is also know. But why? This is not the first time this has happened where I just have no idea when to use them anymore.

What is a z-distribution?

@Michael presumably a standard normal distribution

Use of a $t$-distribution for confidence intervals comes from the particular impact of using $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2}$ to estimate the standard error of the mean.  Confidence intervals for the parameter of a Poisson distribution face different issues so a $t$-distribution is inappropriate; https://www.ine.pt/revstat/pdf/rs120203.pdf looked at 19 possible approaches.

Perhaps the ambiguous description "z-distribution or lambda as it is also know" is something associated with a Poisson random variable. There may be a cool way to solve this problem using the fact that the sum of independent Poisson random variables again is a Poisson random variable, and/or knowing $\sigma = \sqrt{\mu}$.
However, likely Henry is correct that "z-distribution" really is just supposed to be a normal distribution.  Here they are telling you to approximate $\sigma \approx \sqrt{\overline{x}}$ (because the Poisson distribution has $\sigma = \sqrt{\mu}$). This is not the estimate you would use for t-distribution. So you may guess they want you to assume $\sigma$ is essentially "known" (by  approximation from the data) and then use the central limit theorem (CLT):
$$ \frac{\sqrt{7}}{\sigma}\left(\frac{1}{7}\sum_{i=1}^7X_i - \mu\right) \approx N(0,1)$$
It is useful to know $\sigma = \sqrt{\mu}$ since the sample mean estimation of $\mu$ typically has lower variance then the sample mean estimator of $\sigma^2$.
Generally speaking, the t-distribution is used only when you know the data is Gaussian or near-Gaussian, since it uses crucial Gaussian properties such as independence between sample variance and sample mean (this independence does not generally hold for non-Gaussian distributions).  If you have non-Gaussian data then you can either:
(1) Use a central limit theorem (CLT) approximation with some numerical approximation of the potentially unknown $\sigma$ (this seems to be the desired method for the current problem).
(2) If you have lots of data, you can use the method of batch means: Group into batches, assume each batch is large enough so the batch mean is approximately Gaussian, and then use the t-distribution on the batch means. For example if you have 100 samples you can group into 10 batches of 10 samples each, then use a t-distribution with 9 degrees of freedom. In the current problem you only have 7 samples, not enough for the batch mean method.
